# Python pyautogui: "NameError: name 'position' is not defined"

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui as pag

import time

time.sleep(5)

pag.press('H', 'H', 'capslock', 'e', 'capslock', 'L', 'capslock', 'i', 'capslock', interval=2)
```

When I tried to operate this in Python Spyder, I only got an error message:

```
NameError: name 'position' is not defined
```

What is the problem? I don't even try to type in any position function.

By the way, I turn on Caps Lock key before operating it, because I wanted some uppercase letters.

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the full traceback you get, not just the last line.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions), you should pass a list as first argument of press function.

```
import pyautogui as pag

import time

time.sleep(5)

pag.press(['H', 'H', 'capslock', 'e', 'capslock', 'L', 'capslock', 'i', 'capslock'], interval=2)
```